# Автоматическое открытие модального окна через несколько секунд

Tags: javascript, popup

есть модальное окно

```
<div class="remodal itb_popup_form_wrapper" data-remodal-id="form-callback">
        <div data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close js-close-campaign"></div>
        <div class="itb_popup_form_tablet_image"><img data-src="images/tablet.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="itb_popup_form_content ">
            <div class="itb_popup_form_title">Заполните форму и наш сотрудник свяжется с Вами.</div>
            <div class="itb_default_form itb_js_form_ctn">
                <form name="tender_form" data-title="Заявка на подбор тендера" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Заявка на подбор тендера">
                    <input type="email" class="default-input itb_mail_field" name="FORMS[tender][email]" value=""
                        placeholder="Ваш e-mail" size="20" />

                    <div class="itb_default_form_item itb_js_form_item">
                        <input type="name" class="default-input " name="FORMS[tender][NAME]" value=""
                            placeholder="Ваше имя" size="20" />

                    </div>
                    <div class="itb_default_form_item itb_js_form_item">
                        <input type="mail" class="default-input " name="FORMS[tender][MAIL]" value=""
                            placeholder="Email" size="20" />

                    </div>
                    <div class="itb_default_form_item itb_js_form_item">
                        <input type="tel" class="default-input itb_js_inputmask" name="FORMS[tender][PHONE]"
                            value="" placeholder="Телефон" size="20" />

                    </div>
                    <div class="itb_default_form_checkbox_wrap">
                        <div class="itb_default_form_checkbox">
                            <input id="tender_form_agreement" class="itb_js_form_item_checkbox" checked
                                type="checkbox" name="FORMS[tender][agreement_chbx]" />
                            <label for="tender_form_agreement">Я принимаю <a href="/user">условия передачи
                                    информации</a></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itb_default_form_button">
                        <div class="itb_main_red_btn_wrap">
                            <a class="itb_main_red_btn itb_js_send_form" href="#"><span>ЗАКАЗАТЬ ЗВОНОК</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Что нужно добавить чтобы оно открывалось через 15 секунд после загрузки страницы ?

Comment: написать код на JavaScript, который это сделает

Comment: пробовал через setTimeOut не работает

Comment: это все, чем я могу вам помочь на данном этапе. Уточните вопрос, как вы пробовали, и что именно у вас не получилось

Comment: пример - https://jsfiddle.net/3jugcya6/

Answer (score 1):

**vanilla js + bootstrap js modal**

*Модальное окно будет выводится через 15 секунд*

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   setTimeout(function() { //ждём 15 секунд
       $('#modal-order').modal('show'); //вызываем модально окно
   }, 15000);
});
```

vanilla js + bootstrap js modal **+ cookie**

*Модальное окно будет выводится через 15 секунд*

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { //дожидаемся полной загрузки страницы
    if (getCookie('modal_shown') == null) { //проверяем наличие куки и если её нет, то
        setTimeout(function() { //ждём 15 секунд
            setCookie('modal_shown', 'yes', 1); //ставим куку
            $('#modal-order').modal('show'); //вызываем модально окно
        }, 15000);
    }
});

function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = '';
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + '=' + (value || '') + expires + '; path=/';
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + '=';
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    setCookie(name, '', {
        'max-age': -1
    });
}
```

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо. перевёл